# Cauchy's integral formula $\Rightarrow$ Green's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have seen some articles proving Cauchy's integral formula using Green's theorem, but I haven't seen the converse. (And I don't like this approach since, to **completely** prove each theorem, one should know some algebraic topology, but then IMO, Cauchy's integral formula is much easier to prove when one knows algebraic topology)

Is there a natural way to prove Green's theorem using Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: I'm not certain that this is really feasible. You can only prove Cauchy from Green's because you make use of holomorphicity. If you went backwards, I suspect you'd be missing part of Green's theorem. There is a more general form of the Cauchy integral formula which works for smooth functions known as the Cauchy-Pompeiu formula. I suspect that you can derive Green's theorem from it.